# How can I fully factory reset an Optimus 2X P990 with ClockWorkMod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 2.2-froyo, factory-reset, clockworkmod-recovery, lg-optimus-2x

I think I forgot to wipe my cache and something else when I installed Cyanogenmod 7 - which I could reboot into just fine. However, when I went to go back and switch to my vanilla Optimus 2X backup (using the ClockWorkMod Recovery - backup, not advanced backup), I reboot and I get the LG loading screen with the police-line loading bar, but after a couple of seconds that loading bar stops moving and the whole thing is frozen.

So, I take out the battery and go back into ClockWorkMod Recovery using the Vol Down + Power shortcut (which only works in about a third of the start-up attempts, for some reason). Where can I go from here to restore to a factory-reset version of the Optimus 2X's 2.2 Froyo?

Update 10/06/2012 6:54PM +8 UST:

If, in CWM Recovery, I clean the cache and wipe user data, then install CyanogenMod7 from .zip again, it boots and runs fine.

Answer (score 3):

After restoring your backup of the original firmware, in recovery select

```
Wipe Data/Factory Reset
```

This way you have the original firmware (except for the recovery partition) but without any user data.

Comment: Well, I never got around that specific method - maybe others will need the data on their original backup - but thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up being too reluctant to downgrade again! Apparently LG have finally released an Australian update so I just downloaded a stock P990 Froyo ROM, installed it via CWM, wiped data and cache, and everything works fine now! It even fixed a bunch of issues I was having with USB drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this problem myself.

When you install cyanogenmod it changes the filesystem type to EXT4.  However, your stock 2X backup almost definitely used the EXT3 filesystem.

If you want to revert to a stock ROM on the 2X after trying cyanogenmod then the following tool can convert your filesystem type back to EXT3:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1021549

Just download the zip and apply it like a normal ROM in NANDROID or Clockworkmod.  Once it's done just restore your backup as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turn off your phone and then press both the power button and the volume down button at the same time and it will do a factory reset.